# Complex power real and imaginary?

Tags: capacitor, ac, inductor

For the complex power equation S=1/2VI, are the V and I the real and imaginary parts or is it just the magnitude?

For example, if I have V as 3+4i and I as 2+6i, is my complex power just 1/2*(3+4i)(2+6i)?

Thanks!

Comment: V and I are the full phasors.

Comment: Just to be clear with your terminology, by full phasors you mean the the entire a+bi correct?

Comment: As Ignacio said full phasors, complex numbers, a+ib if you like. But your equation is wrong! Can you see why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help: -

[image]
<sub>(source: [electronics-tutorials.ws](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/articles/reactive2.gif?x98918))</sub>

As you can see S does not equal 1/2VI (or do you mean VI/2?)

Comment: In my class we use Vpeak values, and yes I forgot the parenthesis (been a long week :p) so my equation would be (1/2)(VI) where V and I are peak 'full phasor', and VI for Vrms 'full phasor'. And to be fully clear, doing something like S= ((|Vrms|^2)/(R)) (note the absolute value on the Vrms) would yeild the wrong answer, right?

Comment: V\$^2\$/R would be a real power and not an apparent power.

Comment: Concernig your question: Oh yes, it's okay for peak values but you are still missing conjugate operator on current. Then you are right, your comment relation is meaningless and BTW RMS values are definited positive, the absolute value operator is meaningless too.

Answer (score 1):

Your complex voltages are most likely referring to phasors.

Complex power is defined as voltage phasor times **conjugate** current phasor.

\$S=VI^*\$

As for the factor of one-half, it depends if your phasor magnitude represents peak or rms values. The above equation is for rms values; so your example must be defined with peak values (Note: \$V_{rms}=V/\sqrt2\$ and \$I_{rms}=I/\sqrt2\$ which is where the factor of 2 comes from).

\$\therefore S=\frac{1}{2}VI^*\$ for peak values of V and I

So with your numbers:

\$S=\frac{1}{2} (3+j4)(2-j6)\$

(Electrical engineers use \$j\$ for complex unit to avoid confusion with current \$i\$.)

\$S=\frac{1}{2}(30-j10)\$

\$\therefore S=15-j5\$